# excel data uploading is not working in sql database

Tags: c#-3.0

This is pradeep

This is the code of the excel uploading to sql database

protected void btnupload_Click ( object sender, EventArgs e )
   {

```
  //string name = ddloutlet.SelectedValue.ToString ();
  //cal
   try
   {

       System.IO.FileInfo file = new System.IO.FileInfo(fileupload1.PostedFile.FileName);
       string fname = file.Name.Remove((file.Name.Length - file.Extension.Length), file.Extension.Length);
       fname = fname + DateTime.Now.ToString("_ddMMyyyy_HHmmss") + file.Extension;
       fileupload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("locations/") + fname);
       string filexetion = file.Extension;
       if ( filexetion == ".xlsx" )
       {
          excelConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" + "Data Source=" + Server.MapPath ( "locations/" ) + fname + ";" + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;\"";
       }
       else if ( filexetion == ".xls" )
       {
          excelConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" + "Data Source=" + Server.MapPath ( "locations/" ) + fname + ";" + "Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes; \"";
       }
       OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(excelConnectionString);
       OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("Select * FROM [Sheet1$]", connection);
       connection.Open();
       OleDbDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader();
       SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strconnection);
       conn.Open();
       try
       {
           if (dr.Read() == true)
           {
               while (dr.Read())
               {
                   string locationname = dr["Location Name"].ToString();
                   string status = dr["Status"].ToString();
                   if (locationname != "" && status != "")
                   {
                       string query = " select locationname from tbllocations where locationname='" + locationname + "' and outletid='" + Session["outlet_id"].ToString() + "'";
                      // conn.Open();
                       SqlCommand cmdquery = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
                      SqlDataReader drreader;
                      drreader = cmdquery.ExecuteReader();
                       if (drreader.Read())
                       {

                           c = true;
                           ssss = ssss + locationname + ",";
                          // ss = ssss.Split(',');
                       }
                       else
                       {
                           drreader.Close();
                           string qryprduct = "insert into tbllocations(locationname,status,outletid,cityid)values('" + locationname + "','" + status + "','" + Session["outlet_id"].ToString() + "','" + Session["cityid"].ToString() + "')";
                           SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(qryprduct, conn);
                           conn.Close();
                           conn.Open();
                           cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                           lblerror1.Visible = true;
                           lblerror1.Text = "Locations uploaded Sucess";
                           //conn.Close();
                       }
                       drreader.Close();
                   }
               }
               // connection.Close (); conn.Close ();
           }
           else
           {
               lblerror1.Text = "There is a empty excel sheet file,plz check";
               lblerror1.Visible = true;
           }
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           lblerror1.Visible = true;
           lblerror1.Text = "Plz check the excel file formate";
       }
       finally
       {
           connection.Close(); conn.Close();
           bind();
           if (c == true)
           {
               lblerror1.Visible = true;
               lblerror1.Text = "In excel this loactions are already exist. Please check,";
               //for (int i = 0; i < ss.Length; i++)
               //{
                   lblerror3.Visible = true;
                   lblerror3.Text = ssss;
               //}
           }
       }
   }
   catch
   {
   }
```

}

The above code  uploading is  working but in excel 1st record is not uploading ,please tell me the what is the problem and give me suggestion please.

excel data is

Location Name   Status
test1            1
test2            1
test3            1
test4            0
test5            1
test6            0
test7            1
test8            0
test9            1
test10           1

Thanks

Pradeep

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the

```
if (dr.Read() == true)
```

because it is immediately followed by a

```
while (dr.Read())
```

Each of these will read a record and the first one will skip the first row of the file